# Vsync, is there a way to turn it off?

Tags: 16.04

Hi I am very new to Ubuntu so I have no idea what I'm doing.

My issue is that every game I run gets capped at 60 fps even though vsync is turned off in game. When I was on windows I would play at around 120 fps and it felt more smoother than it does now. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 64bit

Comment: Is your display 120Hz? Otherwise it's just pointless.

Comment: Its 60 hz but when I was on windows, i noticed a difference between 60 fps and 120fps, I think the screen tearing helped me out or I just got used to it.

Answer (score 2):

**NVIDIA:**
1. Run nvidia-settings
2. Screen 0 > OpenGl > Sync to VBLank

Hope this helped!

*Source: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3262689*